# WordPress Calendar Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have looked around the WordPress plugin site for some time and so far, no dice. For a personal project, I am looking for a WordPress calendar plugin which provides the following functionality:

- Send invitations to other WordPress users
- Output event list as normal WordPress page
- Automatically detect past events and allow the addition of a report and gallery
- Support private and public events

Obviously, I could set to and write such a plugin, but I'm loathed to take this extra action if there is already a plugin available which will handle most of what I want (even if I need to slightly edit the code).

I did consider using two plugins, something like [Events Manager Extended](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager-extended/) and the [NextGEN Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) to achieve what I want, but would ideally like something in a combined plugin.

Can anyone help identify such a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with events manager http://wp-events-plugin.com/ you can add nextgen gallery shortcodes in the event description ;)!